# "One or more images were not found" error in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to call my photos in database. I'm running at local perfectly but, when I put my files in FTP I got this error:

> Error loading images. One or more images were not found.

Here is my codes that I called from DB:

```
    <?php

    function gella($sayi){
        $tanim = array(
        "1"  => "cubeRandom",
        "2"  => "block",
        "3"  => "cubeStop",
        "4"  => "cubeStopRandom",
        "5"  => "directionTop",
        "6"  => "showBarsRandom",
        "7"  => "horizontal",
        "8"  => "showBars",
        "9"  => "tube",
        "10"  =>  "circles",
        "11" => "glassCube" 
        );
        return $tanim[$sayi];
        }

     $sor = mysql_query("select * from pl_ust_banner");
     while($y = mysql_fetch_object($sor)){
        $ie++;
echo '<li><a href="#Random"><img src="Panel/Sayfalar/UstBanner/'.$y->resim.'" class="'.gella($ie).'" /></a>  </li>';

         }
     ?>
        </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: nothing in your code returns the error *One or more images were not found*

Comment: Upload your images on server mate.

Comment: You need to tell us more about the error and where it comes from. And note that the `mysql_*` functions are depreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because locally the images can be found in your `src`

```
Panel/Sayfalar/UstBanner/
```

Although this is not true when it's on a server. You will need to add your images to the server and change the directory so it goes to the images that are on your server.

Comment: how do you know the server paths are not the same as the local?

Comment: @Dagon Because the OP mentioned this works perfectly locally. If it's not working on the server then the paths aren't the same or the images are not on the server.

Comment: Thanks but I uploaded my images to the server and I changed the directory.I tried to write image's name and Panel/Sayfalar/UstBanner/example.jpg it shows on the web site. But I want to fetch all of the images.

Comment: or the files dont exist or the permissions are wrong or ... random guessing is not helpfull

Comment: @nurdankaraman If you changed the directory could you tell me where the images are located on the server?

Comment: Ahh okay you re right .. Thanks all . it has solved. :)

Comment: @Dagon This isn't random guessing. What I said above is indeed the problem. If files are fine locally vs not found on the server, almost 100% of the time is the directories are not the same. Also not "not found" is not "access denied".

Comment: @nurdankaraman Great, if this solved you problem would you mind marking this as "accepted"?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the full URL path in the src attribute value. `src="http://domain.com/path/to/images/Panel/Sayfalar/UstBanner/..."` Instead of using a relative URI. 
Additionally ensure you have uploaded the images to their respective directories and they have a `644` permission bit (publicly accessible).

You can also validate the existence of the image path prior to echoing it.

```
while($y = mysql_fetch_object($sor)){
    if(false === is_file('/path/to/images/Panel/Sayfalar/UstBanner/' . $y->resim){
       continue;
    }
    //put your echo or other function if the file exists here.
}
```

Comment: State why you are downvoting please.

Comment: It appears someone came in and just downvoted for the heck of it. I don't see how your answer is not useful, seems useful to me +1.